# c# how to get data out of datagrid by buttonclick from button in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

So I have a datagrid where I added a button into. When I click the button in a  row I want the data out of, what is in that row, in a messagebox. I have no clue how to do this...

Here is the XAML code for the button:
`

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Click="BtnAdd_Click" Height="40" Width="80" Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2">
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AddShoppingCart"/>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

`I have tried this:`

```
    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var row = (DataGridRow)grid1.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show(row.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
        }
```

`

So the result I want is the items in the datagrid (from the row where I clicked the button) in a messagebox.

Comment: How is the `DataGrid` being populated? Are you binding to its `ItemsSource`?

Comment: Yes. I am binding from ItemSource

Comment: In that case, the type of `SelectedItem` is not `DataGridRow`. It's the type of the ViewModel bound to the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question I believe you should cast `grid1.SelectedItem` to the type you are using in your data binding instead of `DataGridRow` so it would be like `var row = (MyTypeVm)grid1.SelectedItem;`, and in the class representing that type you can override the `.ToString()` method to display that data however you like it.

in example:
Your type would be something like this

```
public class MyTypeVm
{
   public string MyStringProperty {get;set}
   public int MyIntProperty {get;set}
   public override string ToString()
   {
     return MyStringProperty + MyIntProperty.ToString();
   }  
}
```